# How should I say this hour in words: "03:01:00"?

Tags: time, reading-aloud

How should I say this hour in words: "**03:01**:00"?

> 1. It's three and one minute **o'clock**.
> 2. It's three and one minute.

Or the word "o'clock" can be said only in hours with two zeros (1:00, 2:00, 3:00)?

Answer (score 2):

You should say:

> It is one minute past three (o-clock) in the morning.

or

> It's one minute past three a.m.

But lots of people would say informally. O-three-O-one.

Comment: I was with you until the last statement. I wouldn’t expect to hear that very often, particularly not “informally.”

Comment: Thank you. Then I have to say "o'clock"? In what cases of hours and minutes (mix) I have to say "o'clock"?

Comment: "O'clock" is only used with hours, not with minutes. I would say that Ronald Sole's "one minute past three o'clock" is possible, but rare: only when there are no minutes is it common

Comment: I would say "three oh one" is common, but "oh three oh one" much less so.

Comment: @ColinFine Agreed!

Answer (score 1):

Dropping "minute" is common aswell:

> I arrived at *one past three*

Or inversely for 2:59 :

> I arrived at *one till three*

Without an "AM"/"PM" or other context people will assume you mean 3:01 PM

Answer (score 0):

Are time-telling telephone services still a thing?  If not, back when they were, the voice would say “At the tone, the time will be three O one, exactly. *Beep* At the tone, the time will be three O one and ten seconds. *Beep*”